# Is there any other way to select HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt that is there any other way to select HTML element if I cannot use `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()` ?

Comment: There's querySelector, getElementsByName, etc. What is your actual question?

Comment: why can't you use at least `getElementById()`?

Comment: Please explain why you can not use these functions, it can help to provide an answer.

Comment: I guess he might want to have jquery type css selectors

Comment: Jaydev - Why can't you use those?! Please explain.

Comment: the HTML is generated dynamically and do not have class or id. still I want to select particular single tag, so asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 main ways of querying DOM:

```
getElementById
getElementsByTagName
getElementsByName
getElementsByClassName (except IE<9)
querySelector (except IE<8 and IE8 in compat mode)
```

All of them can search inside any other element. All of them excepts the last one return live collections.